# IF table is empty insert another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can i check if table A is empty? And if is empty, how can i insert table B content to table A? (they are identical). I would like to create something like this if table A is empty :

```
INSERT INTO tableA
SELECT * FROM tableB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO tableA
SELECT * FROM tableB
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableA)
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO tableA
SELECT * FROM tableB
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you one more time @forpas:)